# SQL Distinct Group By Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table data's

```
id    id_order    name    phone    price
1       4E0        A       789      $100
2       4E0        A       789      $100
3       4LK        A       789      $200
4       2LP        B       420      $50
5       DK2        B       420      $80
```

i want result be like the rows of distinct (id_order) where phone = "789"

```
    id    id_order    name    phone    price
    1       4E0        A       789      $100
    3       4LK        A       789      $200
```

or

```
   id    id_order    name    phone    price
   2       4E0        A       789      $100
   3       4LK        A       789      $200
```

I tried this but didn't get desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (id_order), * from table_name WHERE phone= "789";
```

Comment: I'm not following. Which result are you looking for?

Comment: Where is phone=420? Is the price average or minimum or random? Which of the IDs did you choose and how?

Comment: Why not also id's 4 an 5? Also... you can't have two different result sets from one sql statement. What are you are wanting here?

Comment: You just want it to decide randomly whether you get id 1 or 2 back since they share the same `id_order`? Like... which one would YOU want back in that condition? What if they have different prices (or is that not possible in this data set)? This is all very confusing with that "OR" you have in there.

Comment: edited @JNevill

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses to make things clearer, i.e. do `SELECT DISTINCT id_order, ...`.

Comment: @SouravDas The "OR" is what's confusing, not the unnecessary parenthesis. Do you want the query to randomly return either of these results?

Comment: either result because i want all the rows of distinct (id_order) where phone  = "789" @Error_2646

Comment: @SouravDas That doesn't make sense though. A query can only have 1 result, unless something is random.

Comment: i know but either result will server my purpose @Error_2646

Comment: Does it have to be limited to two records? I just can't understand why '2       4E0        A       789      $100' is excluded in the first example result

Comment: because i want distinct "id_order" rows for phone = "789"..
here 3 records found for phone = "789" and wheres 2 id_orders are distinct (4EO and 4LK) @Error_2646

Comment: If the id does not matter, do not select the id; `SELECT *` is generally considered lazy at the best of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    min(id) id,    
    id_order,    
    name,    
    phone,    
    price 
  from yourtable 
  group by id_order, name, phone, price
```

Comment: Use min and group by like above

Comment: Yeah, the solution should be along these lines, but the question is so incomplete...

Comment: Hmm, if you add a `WHERE phone = '789'`, I think it's what the OP seems to need.

Comment: I think he just provided a sample of what the result should look like

Answer (score 1):

To always return one row per id_order - even if the name, phone or price is different - have a sub-query that returns each id_order's lowest id. `JOIN` with that result:

```
select t1.*
from table_name t1
join (select min(id) minid, id_order
      from table_name
      group by id_order) t2
    on t1.id = t2.minid and t1.id_order = t2.id_order
where t1.phone = 789
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select * from table_name;
         id id_order name       phone       price
=========== ======== ==== =========== ===========
          1 4E0      A            789         100
          2 4E0      A            789         100
          3 4LK      A            789         200
          4 2LP      B            420          50
          5 DK2      B            420          80

                  5 rows found

SQL>select t1.*
SQL&from table_name t1
SQL&join (select min(id) minid, id_order
SQL&      from table_name
SQL&      group by id_order) t2
SQL&    on t1.id = t2.minid and t1.id_order = t2.id_order
SQL&where t1.phone = 789;
         id id_order name       phone       price
=========== ======== ==== =========== ===========
          1 4E0      A            789         100
          3 4LK      A            789         200

                  2 rows found
```